# Monitor access to a symlink with Pyinotify

Tags: python, linux, inotify, pyinotify

I'm trying to monitor the access to symlinks, i.e. if a symlink is used to access a file. With Pyinotify I can monitor access to files, but I do not get any events when reading a file through its watched symlink (e.g. `head symlink_to_file.txt`).

To test this, I used the `loop.py` [example from Pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/loop.py) and simply replaced the folder `/tmp`.

From reading the documentation I think that by using `IN_DONT_FOLLOW`, I should get events for accessing the symlink instead of the file it points to, but modifying the line that adds the watch to

```
wm.add_watch('./', pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS | pyinotify.IN_DONT_FOLLOW)
```

does not yield any additional events.

Then how do I monitor the access of symlinks? Is this the wrong place to add `IN_DONT_FOLLOW`? Am I trying to use the inotify interface for something it was not designed to do?